# Opencl function cl::Kernel always gives error of -46

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to compile an OpenCL kernel using c++ binding, pretty standard stuff.
However, the function `cl::Kernel` always gives an error of -46 (*CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME*)

My code seems clean, so I searched a lot regarding what the error could be...
I tried to make sure that both the CPP file and the kernel file encoding is the same, tried to make sure they all the use the same case, but no luck.

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <CL/cl.hpp>

int main()
{

    /*
    *    Initialize OPENCL
    */
    std::vector<cl::Platform> g_opencl_platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&g_opencl_platforms);
    if(g_opencl_platforms.size()==0)
    {
        std::cout << "[Main] Error initializing OpenCL : No platform available" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cl::Platform g_opencl_default_platform = g_opencl_platforms[0];
    std::cout << "[Main] Using OpenCL platform [" << g_opencl_default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << "]" << std::endl;

    std::vector<cl::Device> g_opencl_default_platform_devices;
    g_opencl_default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &g_opencl_default_platform_devices);
    if(g_opencl_default_platform_devices.size()==0)
    {
        std::cout << "[Main] Error initializing OpenCL : No device found for platoform [" << g_opencl_default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << "]" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cl::Device g_opencl_default_device = g_opencl_default_platform_devices[0];
    std::cout << "[Main] Using OpenCL device [" << g_opencl_default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << "]" << std::endl;

    cl::Context g_opencl_default_context({g_opencl_default_device});

    std::string g_current_working_directory = std::filesystem::current_path();

    /*
    *    std::filesystem::current_path() returns the working directory with double quotes, remove thoses.
    */
    g_current_working_directory.erase(std::remove(g_current_working_directory.begin(),g_current_working_directory.end(),'\"'),g_current_working_directory.end());   

    std::stringstream tmpFileNameStringStream;
    tmpFileNameStringStream << g_current_working_directory << "/Include/OpenCL";
    std::string g_opencl_kernels_directory = tmpFileNameStringStream.str();

    cl::Program::Sources g_opencl_kernels_sources;

    std::cout << "[Main] Checking for OpenCL kernel(s) to compile in directory [" << g_opencl_kernels_directory << "]" << std::endl ;
    for (const auto & entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(g_opencl_kernels_directory))
    {
        std::string tmpFilePath = entry.path();
        tmpFilePath.erase(std::remove(tmpFilePath.begin(),tmpFilePath.end(),'\"'),tmpFilePath.end());
        std::cout << "[Main] Loading OpenCL kernel [" << tmpFilePath << "]" << std::endl ;

        std::fstream kernel_file(tmpFilePath, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
        std::string tmp_kernel_source( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(kernel_file)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() );             

        std::cout << tmp_kernel_source << std::endl;
        g_opencl_kernels_sources.push_back({tmp_kernel_source.c_str(),tmp_kernel_source.size()});
    }

    std::cout << "[Main] Compiling [" << g_opencl_kernels_sources.size() << "] OpenCL source(s)" << std::endl ;
    cl::Program g_opencl_default_program(g_opencl_default_context,g_opencl_kernels_sources);

    cl_int build_result = g_opencl_default_program.build({g_opencl_default_device});
    if(build_result != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "[Main] Error compiling OpenCL source(s) :" << g_opencl_default_program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(g_opencl_default_device) << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }      



    cl::CommandQueue g_opencl_default_command_queue(g_opencl_default_context,g_opencl_default_device); 



    cl_uchar A[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    cl_uchar B[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0};

    cl::Buffer buffer_A(g_opencl_default_context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,sizeof(cl_uchar)*10);
    cl::Buffer buffer_B(g_opencl_default_context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,sizeof(cl_uchar)*10);
    cl::Buffer buffer_C(g_opencl_default_context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_uchar)*10);

    g_opencl_default_command_queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_uchar)*10,A);
    g_opencl_default_command_queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_uchar)*10,B);    

    cl_int kernel_creation_result = 0;
    cl::Kernel kernel_add = cl::Kernel(g_opencl_default_program,"rien",&kernel_creation_result);

    if(kernel_creation_result != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "[Main] Error creating kernel [" << kernel_creation_result << "]" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }


    return 1;

}
```

Here is the rien.cl file (Located in current working directory Include/OpenCL/rien.cl)

```
__kernel void rien()
{
}
```

Here is the output :

```
[Main] Using OpenCL platform [NVIDIA CUDA]
[Main] Using OpenCL device [GeForce GTX 1050]
[Main] Checking for OpenCL kernel(s) to compile in directory [/mnt/Data/Temporary/test/Include/OpenCL]
[Main] Loading OpenCL kernel [/mnt/Data/Temporary/test/Include/OpenCL/simple.cl]
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable

__kernel void rien()
{
}

[Main] Compiling [1] OpenCL source(s)
[Main] Error creating kernel [-46]
```

Code is compiled with the following :

```
g++ --std=c++2a -O3 -Wall main.cpp -lOpenCL
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: __kernel function should not return anything

Comment: Indeed, a void kernel returning something is kinda stupid..i will correct my post. The error still happens though.

Comment: It seems to me that using tmp_kernel_source.c_str() is invalid in this case, because the lifetime of "tmp_kernel_source" is "for loop".

Comment: Yes, its c_str being a pointer which becomes obsolete in next for loop step.